# Enqueue array of T to ConcurrentQueue<T>

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency

I would like to run a simple hardware data acquisition experiment (based on National Instruments hardware).

The actual acquisition runs in a thread where the data (in the form of doubles) is made available as double[]. The array of returned values can be of arbitrary length, depending on how fast data is coming in.

I would need to add this data to the global dataset by appending it.

In C++ or the like you could solve this by adding new data to a pre allocated buffer of sorts and moving a pointer up the buffer.

In C# I am not so sure, can I do something like:

Enqueue(double[]) to a ConcurrentQueue ?

It would seem stupid to have to iterate the double[] and call enqueue on each element..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you define a `ConcurrentQueue<double[]>` and then you can do:

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<double[]> concurrentQueue = 
      new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<double[]>();
concurrentQuey.Enqueue(new double[] { 1, 3, 4, });
concurrentQuey.Enqueue(new double[] { 4, 5, 6, });
```

Later if you need a flattened array of double items then you can do:

```
double[] flattenedArray = concurrentQueue.SelectMany(r => r).ToArray();
```